# Unable to download file from ftp server using java

Tags: java, ftp

I was trying to download files from ftp server using java, but am getting the error message. I have tried upto my knowledge but couldnt able to resolve the issue...
The full source code given below..

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.*;


public class FTPDownloadFileDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String server = "www.mydomain.com";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "username";
    String pass = "password";

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {

        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        String remoteFile1 = "/xxxx/xxx/2015/01(Jan)/01-02/filename.PDF";
        File downloadFile1 = new File("E:/Test/filename.PDF");
        OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
        boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
        outputStream1.close();

        if (success) {
            System.out.println("File #1 has been downloaded successfully.");
        }


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Where I committed the mistake..?
Please help me...

EDIT:
The error message as below

```
 Error: Permission denied: recv failed
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: recv failed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetInputStream.__read(TelnetInputStream.java:114)
at org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetInputStream.run(TelnetInputStream.java:535)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient._flushOutputStream(TelnetClient.java:77)
at org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetOutputStream.flush(TelnetOutputStream.java:137)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:442)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:520)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:569)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.quit(FTP.java:781)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.logout(FTPClient.java:706)
at FTPDownloadFileDemo.main(FTPDownloadFileDemo.java:60)
```

Comment: Of the statements in your `try` block, remove the last statements one at a time until there is no error or only one error, then tell us what the last statement you removed was: that's the statement that caused the error.

Comment: @Saposhiente 'boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);' this line caused the error...